# Javascript and Python variable differences

Tags: javascript, python

I've just started learning Javascript and used to Python previously.

Python variables work as a reference to, a 'block' in memory. Other aliases can point to block in memory and which is cleaned up by the garbage collection when there are no more references remaining which point to it.

However I'm not sure if this is the same in Javascript? Does Javascript use direct pointers, rather than references?
So does javascript have the same shallow or deep copy  differences that Python does?
(I've heard that JS may not have the concept of mutability or immutability, so this may not be the case).

Can anyone explain how Javascript variables work in detail as I can't picture this well?

Thanks.

PS I'm still pretty new to programming so apologies if my terminology is a bit wonky.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between a reference to memory, and a pointer to memory? (I could look it up myself, but I'm more interested in your personal mental model of the concepts)

Comment: On Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) is an article about Memory Management in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: You may want to go to a chat room for a discussion, you'll find a better answer because this question doesn't involves any code error. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: FWIW, I found this quite useful when I started with JS: http://jfine.bitbucket.org/docs/js4py/index.html

Comment: Good point - I was struggling with how to describe a reference and a pointer.  I suppose by reference I meant that the actual 'physical' memory address was hidden and the memory address maybe changed by the compiler if this turns out to be more efficient.  A pointer I imagined to be absolute and a fixed memory address as used in e.g. assembler.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, javascript works in a similar way.

booleans, numbers, and strings are stored by value. So, in this code snippet, for example,

```
var a = 122;
var b = 122;
```

`a === b` will be true.

Everything else, however, is stored by reference and automatically garbage-collected as you described in your question. So, for example, in this code snippet,

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`a === b` will be false.

Edit:

In Python, array and dictionary equality are by value, but class instances are equal only if they are the same instance. In javascript, an `Object` is basically a dictionary where the keys must be strings. Because Objects are used in javascript to fill the same role as class instances in Python (you'd be surprised at how well it works), Objects are equal only if they are the same Object. Arrays inherit from Object, so they are also by reference.

Comment: Thanks and is anything mutable, i.e. are operations on string, arrays etc.. always create a copy?

Comment: (Also for arrays/lists testing that last equality in the python interpreter I get true ?)

Comment: If I understand your first question, you're asking whether, for example, the following builds a new array from scratch in memory or whether it keeps the old one and adds to it: `var a = [1,2]; a.push(3);`. I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Also, I edited my answer to fix my misunderstanding of Python array equality.

Comment: Thanks , it looks like JS arrays are mutable and a list of the mutating methods are here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Mutator_methods.   Python I've since learned that object references are passed by value. Good writeup here: http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/